# React-Router's Redirect throws a webpack error when i use it

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

So I am writing a React app, and basically I'm trying to do a redirect from one path to another using the react-router-dom package. But whenever my path matches the 'from' attribute of the Redirect element, I get a webpack error. Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.sass";
import HeaderComponent from "./HeaderComponent";
import BodyComponent from "./BodyComponent";
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Switch,
    Link,
    Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            increment: 0
        };

        this.parallax = this.parallax.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", this.parallax);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.parallax);
    }

    parallax() {
        if (
            document.documentElement.scrollTop <
            document.getElementById("hero").clientHeight
        ) {
            let scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop,
                offset = Math.floor(scrollTop / 3);
            this.setState({ increment: offset }, () =>
                console.log(this.state.increment)
            );
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <HeaderComponent
                        increment={this.state.increment}
                        days={this.state.days}
                    />
                    <Switch>
                        <Redirect from="/calabar" to="/tokyo" />
                        <Route
                            path="/:city"
                            render={props => <BodyComponent {...props} />}
                        />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

This is a screenshot of the error I get:

[image: Snapshot of React-Router Redirect Error]

**EDIT**

When the url is set to another path that does not match the "from" attribute of the redirect, it works just fine as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Please any help on what I'm doing wrong? Or could it be an installation error? Or an error from react-router-dom itself?

Comment: Could you post the versions of react-router-dom and webpack please?

Comment: @Sreeram the version of react-router-dom is 5.0.1 and the version of webpack is 4.29.6

Comment: This same setup is working for me. So the problem has to be from somewhere else. Is it working without the redirect?

Comment: Yes. It works perfectly until the url matches the "from" attribute of the Redirect element. In the screenshot, the error is thrown when the url is set to "/calabar". If it's set to anything else, it works without a hassle.

Comment: Tried clearing the cache? incognito mode etc?

Comment: Just did those now (clearing my browser cache and testing incognito mode). No success..or did you mean clearing npm's cache?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195755/discussion-between-sreeram-and-eric-mcwinner).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Redirect does not work inside Switches for me. The reason why, I can't figure out to this day. After giving up on React-Router for a few weeks and coming back to try the Redirect without nesting it in a Switch it worked. So an alternate way of achieving what I wanted would be:

```
<Redirect from="/calabar" to="/tokyo" />
/**Longer list of Redirects**/
<Switch>
   <Route
      path="/:city"
      render={props => <BodyComponent {...props} />}
   />
   /**Extra Routes whose path only match the to attribute of the Redirects**/
</Switch>
```

In the API docs though, they nest a Redirect in a Switch, but I don't know why it spits an error when **I** try it.